# Read CSV in PowerShell and Map Drives

Tags: powershell, import-csv

I'm Looking to read from a .CSV and then use the data to map a drive. The file looks like this:

```
Location, UNC1, UNC2      
USA, \\Server1\Data, \\Server1\Shared
EMEA, \\Server2\Data, \\Server2\Shared
```

Tricky part is I wanna read the data from a CSV and then present in a list box (guess I have to summon VBS?) but only show the region in the box. Then when I choose the region, it maps the 2 UNC's to the local machine.

I've read a few posts and will need Import-CSV - just looking for a jumping off point.

Any suggestions?

Comment: check https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/553491-issues-using-this-powershell-script-on-a-mapped-network-drive

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please review and edit your question with a [Minimal Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please do provide the code you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally we ask that you try to do something yourself, then we are here to help troubleshoot along the way. Next time you ask a question please make an attempt to code it yourself then come asking for help when you get stuck.

I just did this for fun real quick because it was pretty easy, enjoy.

```
function Map-Drive(){
    if($ComboBox1.text -eq "USA"){
        New-PSDrive -Name K -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $csv.UNC1[0] -Persist -Scope Global
        New-PSDrive -Name L -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $csv.UNC2[0] -Persist -Scope Global
    }
    if($ComboBox1.text -eq "EMEA"){
        New-PSDrive -Name M -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $csv.UNC1[1] -Persist -Scope Global
        New-PSDrive -Name N -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $csv.UNC2[1] -Persist -Scope Global
    }
}

$csv = import-csv "\\server\folder\test.csv" -Delimiter ","

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$Form                            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.ClientSize                 = '319,63'
$Form.text                       = "Regional Drive Map"
$Form.TopMost                    = $false

$ComboBox1                       = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$ComboBox1.text                  = "comboBox"
$ComboBox1.BackColor             = "#d7ebff"
$ComboBox1.width                 = 143
$ComboBox1.height                = 54
$ComboBox1.location              = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20,18)
$ComboBox1.Font                  = 'OCR A,12,style=Bold'

$Button1                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button1.BackColor               = "#eaeaea"
$Button1.text                    = "Map Drive"
$Button1.width                   = 107
$Button1.height                  = 30
$Button1.location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(174,14)
$Button1.Font                    = 'OCR A,10'

$ComboBox1.DataSource = [system.Collections.ArrayList]$csv
$ComboBox1.DisplayMember = 'Location'

$Button1.Add_Click({Map-Drive})

$Form.controls.AddRange(@($ComboBox1,$Button1))
#Finally Show our GUI
$Form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort - I was just looking for a starting point. I have a script that someone wrote in VB and wanted to port over to PS.